# Windows Installer (Trial Run)

Tags: 12.04, installation, uninstall, testing

So Windows Installer is like a trial run in my mind from what I see.
It partitions your hard drive so you can use Ubuntu, but Ubuntu relies on Windows remaining on the system, yes?

So I have 2 questions:

1.
If I don't like Ubuntu how do I remove it?

2.
If I like Ubuntu do I just use the Ubuntu part to make the disk?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like it you can just uninstall it from the Windows Control Panel like so: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation

If you do like it, you can migrate it to its own partition or remove Windows entirely by following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are talking about installing using Wubi:

- Yes it does rely on Windows, as it is installed as Windows software inside Windows, and if Windows crashes your Ubuntu system will go with it as well. Wubi is good if you want to get a hang of Ubuntu safely and without altering your system.
- It's not a trial run, as it is free, and you can use it as long as you want.
- It doesn't creates a new partition. It uses space inside your Windows partition. This space it is easily freed when you uninstall Wubi from the Control Panel in Windows.
- If you really like Ubuntu, I would suggest you to make a new partition of say 30 GB, and then do a full install on it. By full install, I mean booting from a pendrive or CD. It will give you fewer troubles and a more stable system.